# Google Sheets Script - Decrease the Value of a Cell by a Generated Range of Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I have a cell with a Value (i.e 1,000) and a Range of 3 Cells that will generate a value based on some conditions. When the Range generates a Value in either of the 3 Cells within the Range, I would like my original 1,000 to be decreased by the sum of the generated ones.

Is this possible? I've been trying a few scripts but can't get it right.

```
function addValue() { var sheetName = "POK_1" ; 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
 var range = ss.getRange("A1"); var value = "J3" }
```

Comment: Definitely possible, show code you have tried so far and where it is not working.

Comment: I am new to Script Editor so I my code is not quite what I am looking for. function addValue() {

var sheetName = "POK_1" ;

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
var range = ss.getRange("A1");
var value = "J3"
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log(e);
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "A2" || e.range.getA1Notation() == "A3" || e.range.getA1Notation() == "A4"){ // Only run if any of the three values are changed.
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("first");
    var data = ss.getRange("A1:A4").getValues();// The main value (A1 and the ones to subtract (A2:A4).
    data[0][0] = data[0][0] - (data[1][0] + data[2][0] + data[3][0]);
    ss.getRange("A1").setValue(data[0][0]);
  }
}
```

This function will automatically subtract all three values from the main one every time either of the three gets changed. This assumes your values are in `A1:A4` for simplicity. You should also take a look at [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) to learn about working with GAS and sheets.

**UPDATE**

This code will be a simple subtraction between two cells, and assigning the result to the first one:

```
function sub(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var a = ss.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var b = ss.getRange("C1").getValue();
  ss.getRange("B1").setValue(a-b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give it a shot, but by your description that is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: It cannot read the property Range from undefined in line 3, is there something else I should edit in your coding? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You'd see that message if you try running it from the editor, because the code is on an `onEdit()` trigger, it will run when the sheet is edited, try saving your code and then making a change to `A2` in the Sheet.

Comment: Thank you I do see it working correctly now, only my generated values are randomly generated with Randbetween, however once they generate one time and the total value is decreased, the generated value loses its formula and does not automatically change again. I may be able to work it out from here though!

Comment: I updated the code, try it this way and it shouldn't overwrite your formulas

Comment: It's very close! The decrease only happens when I manually change one of the numbers in the range, unfortunately not when the numbers change automatically though. Does the onEdit function have an AutomaticEdit counterpart?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, you could have it in a time-based trigger, or if you need it more pressingly, you could add it as a macro to better react to what you need. How are your decreasers being changed? meaning, what triggers the formula

Comment: The decreasers appear in the range based on the condition that its value is greater than another randomly generated value. If the value is greater then it is shown in the range and decreased from the total. Ideally as these are being generated it would automatically decrease.

Comment: No it is done through an IF(AND) formula. Another way around would be for the generated values to be automatically copy and pasted into a list, but I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: You have some options, you could turn the script into a macro, you could also make the process of generating the decrease values a script and then it would be easy to add the code I wrote. As for the list you mentioned it still leaves the issue of not having a trigger for it. I believe your best choice is add the decrease to the script.

Comment: Here is the exact formula for how a decrease is generated. =IF(AND(O4>O5,K4>L5),K4-L5,"") for decrease 1 and =IF(AND(O4>O5,M4>N5),M4-N5,"") for decrease 2 my total value the one being decreased is at D5

Comment: Could you share a sanitized version of your sheet? then I'd be able to think of a good approach for managing everything

Comment: I found a way to make the script much simpler, now all I need to work out is a script that will decrease the value of a cell by the value of another cell. Is there a simple script for this? Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer to include a simple subtraction method.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working! Please consider marking the answer as accepted so the question is marked as solved for others.